# Can I add a shortcut application to the menu.xml?

Tags: android, menu, shortcut

I want to add an application shortcut in the following list

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:icon="@drawable/tw_action_bar_icon_playstore" android:id="@id/options_menu_market" android:title="@string/options_menu_market" />
    <item android:icon="@drawable/tw_action_bar_icon_edit" android:id="@id/options_menu_edit" android:title="@string/options_menu_edit" />
</menu>
```

Usually add the following code with targetPackage

```
 <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/#">
        <intent android:targetPackage="#" android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN" android:targetClass="#" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

How do I add the same code, but in the previous list menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity hosting the Menu, watch for a click on that menu item, then start an Intent for the target Activity.

Comment: Thank you for your response I really appreciate this
But can you give me an example